# On embedding a sort of $CW$ complexes to a Euclidean space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I'd like to know if a finite dimensional, locally finite, $CW$ complex with countable cells can always be embedded to a Euclidean space. All I know is that it holds in the case $\dim=1$.

Comment: This is true for finite CW complexes; see Hatcher A.10. Alternatively I would bet that the spaces you describe have finite [topological dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension#Relationship_between_dimensions), so - when compact - can embed into a Euclidean space. I have no idea about the noncompact case.

Comment: Maybe write your CW complex as a union of a sequence of finite subcomplexes, and show that you can embed each of the finite subcomplexes in a way that's compatible with the inclusions? Then take a limit of such embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think page noumber 181  of this link: http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/tom-readings/ranicki-intro  will be useful for your purpose.